# Wrapping one-line div's around an img (not text)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to get a bunch of div's to wrap around an image, but am failing.

Since pasting HTML doesn't seem to work in StackOverFlow, here is my current attempt at emulating a Outlook 2010 contact entry.

Source from: http://www.perfmon.com/download/contactdivtest.htm 
(edit: or check out @Hristo's cool online editor )

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<style type="text/css">
.contactLarge{
    width: 250px;
    height: 220px;
}
 img.picture {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
}
.contactLarge item{
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contactLarge">
<div style="background-color:#C5CED8;clear:both">title </div>
<img class="picture" width="100" height="200" src="ContactBigLeftBorder.png" alt="">
First, Last <br>
First, Last <br>
First, Last <br>
First, Last <br>
<div style="width:100%;font-weight:bold; float: left;">LastName, Firstname</div>
<div style="font-weight:bold;clear:both;"  >CompanyName</div>
<div >Title</div>
<div >Work#</div>
<div >Mobile#</div>
<div >Home</div>
<div >email1</div>
<div >email2</div>
<div >email3</div>
<div >Street</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9;  float:left;"  >City,</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9; float:left;"  >State</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9;"  >Zip</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9; clear:left;  float:left;"  >httppage</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9; ">im</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make all the div's move up and wrap around the image?  I really hope I'm not missing something simple...

Here is the target layout I'm attempting:

[alt text http://perfmon.com/download/contactdivtest.bmp](http://perfmon.com/download/contactdivtest.bmp)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on putting code into questions.

Comment: Could you post an image of what you're trying to accomplish? I can't quite tell from the html & don't use Outlook 2010.

Comment: try using span instead of div for your specific solution

Comment: you can post the html. In the editor, enter your HTML, then highlight it and click the button that looks like binary code to format it. If you are on a mobile device and dont have the buttons, then just indent all your code 4 spaces to have it be recognized as code.

Comment: @Mike, @DHuntrods I update the question. Sorry for the delay, I had to catch my train and was in the subway.  I'll be experimenting with the layout and your sugguestions now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foor your specific solution span can work better for you:

check the version with span:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title> 
</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
.contactLarge{
    width: 250px;
    height: 220px;
}
.contactLarge span{
    font-weight: bold;
}
 img.picture {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
}
.contactLarge item{
}
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div class="contactLarge"> 
<div style="background-color:#C5CED8;clear:both">title </div> 
<img class="picture" width="100" height="200" src="http://www.perfmon.com/download/ContactBigLeftBorder.png" alt=""> 
First, Last <br> 
First, Last <br> 
First, Last <br> 
First, Last <br> 
<span>LastName, Firstname</span> <br /> 
<span>CompanyName</span> <br /> 
<span >Title</span> <br> 
<span >Work#</span> <br> 
<span >Mobile#</span> <br> 
<span >Home</span> <br> 
<span >email1</span> <br> 
<span >email2</span> <br> 
<span >email3</span> <br> 
<span >Street</span> <br> 
<span style="background-color:#F1F5F9;  float:left;"  >City,</span> <br> 
<span style="background-color:#F1F5F9; float:left;"  >State</span> <br> 
<span style="background-color:#F1F5F9;"  >Zip</span> <br> 
<span style="background-color:#F1F5F9;"  >httppage</span> <br> 
<span style="background-color:#F1F5F9; ">im</span> <br> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for going through the trouble of fixing my spans.  Lesson learned :)

Answer (score 1):

A `<div>` is a block level element - this means that it automatically clears to a new line and has 100% width. Without seeing your html or css it's hard to see where you're going wrong but try using `float`:

```
div {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**Edit:**
Now that you've posted a picture of what you want I can say that you'll probably want something like this:
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="foo.jpg" />
    <div id="content">
        <p>Blah blah</p>
        <p>More blah blah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}
```

Just make sure that the width of the img + width of the inner div is less than the width of the containing div.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to a css n00b!

Comment: Semantically a p is a paragraph of text, whereas span means nothing semantically. It's entirely up to you on what you chose to go for, keeping in mind that p is a block element and span is inline.

Answer (score 1):

Div is a block-level element.  It will take up full width and generate a break before and after.

Img is, by default, an inline element.  You want to wrap it in another one (not float).  Either use span's instead (span is div's inline brother) or set the css `display` property to `inline` on the div.

Comment: Thanks, how can I tell if a given tag is inline or block?

Comment: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html is a list of block level elements. The remaining tags are inline.

Answer (score 1):

A very useful trick for these sorts of things is the "display: inline-block".

It displays things inline (so the wrapping will work), but leaves you with almost the full configurability of a block-level element.

Comment: I'm seeing that div vs span may be a religious debate... so I'm taking no sites and +1'ing each side.  Thanks for the tip.  I like options when designing :)

Comment: Eh, it's not so much about religion, just what you find logical. For me spans never quite made sense, there are usually semantically better options for inline text (label, em, strong etc.)

Comment: Good to know.  And yea, I can only see myself using spans in situations where I'm binding to data... but that makes me think... perhaps I should open a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a "textbox" div around your text and float it left you should be good to go. See:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<style type="text/css">
.contactLarge{
    width: 250px;
    height: 220px;
}
 img.picture {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
}
.textbox {
    float: left;
}
.contactLarge item{
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contactLarge">
<div style="background-color:#C5CED8;clear:both">title </div>
<img class="picture" width="100" height="200" src="ContactBigLeftBorder.png" alt="">

<div class="textbox">
First, Last <br>
First, Last <br>
First, Last <br>

First, Last <br>
<div style="width:100%;font-weight:bold; float: left;">LastName, Firstname</div>
<div style="font-weight:bold;clear:both;"  >CompanyName</div>
<div >Title</div>
<div >Work#</div>
<div >Mobile#</div>
<div >Home</div>
<div >email1</div>
<div >email2</div>

<div >email3</div>
<div >Street</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9;  float:left;"  >City,</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9; float:left;"  >State</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9;"  >Zip</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9; clear:left;  float:left;"  >httppage</div>
<div style="background-color:#F1F5F9; ">im</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```